# Toggling mobile hamburger submenu with click

Tags: javascript, typescript, tailwind-css

Trying to achieve the following. When the user hovers the "Discover" link, it works in showing the dropdown, however I'd like it to close when you click the down arrow. I tried a few things to no avail. I am sure someone knows the answer to this in a heartbeat, however I am not that JS smart :) Anyway code below. Thanks.

HTML

```
   <li class="flex relative group">
        <.link navigate={~p"/discover"} class="text-lg">Discover<i class="nav-arrow fa-solid fa-chevron-down fa-2xs [li:hover>a>&]:rotate-180 transition ml-0.5"></i></.link>
              <!-- Discover Dropdown -->
              <ul class="discover show absolute bg-white top-[32px] transform scale-0 group-hover:scale-100 transition origin-top shadow-inner border-gray rounded-xl w-72">
                <li class="px-1 mt-0.5 text-sm hover:font-bold leading-8 font-normal"><.link navigate={~p"/discover?vertical=col-college-planning"}>College Planning</.link></li>
                <li class="px-1 text-sm hover:font-bold leading-8 font-normal"><.link navigate={~p"/discover?vertical=hsc-high-school"}>HS Success</.link></li>
                <li class="px-1 mb-0.5 text-sm hover:font-bold leading-8 font-normal"><.link navigate={~p"/discover?vertical=careers"}>Careers</.link></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

JS

```
const NavigationMenu = () => {

    const mobile_icon = document.getElementById("mobile-icon") as HTMLElement;
    const mobile_menu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu") as HTMLElement;
    const mobile_menu_bg = document.getElementById(
      "mobile-menu-background",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const hamburger_icon = document.querySelector(
      "#mobile-icon i",
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const nav_arrow = document.querySelector(".nav-arrow") as HTMLElement;
    const discover = document.querySelector(".discover") as HTMLElement;

    nav_arrow.onclick = function () {
      discover.classList.toggle("show");
    };

    function openCloseMenu(): void {
      mobile_menu.classList.toggle("block");
      mobile_menu.classList.toggle("active");
      mobile_menu_bg.classList.toggle("bg-black/60");
    }

    function changeIcon(): void {
      hamburger_icon.classList.toggle("fa-xmark");
    }

    mobile_icon.addEventListener("click", openCloseMenu);
    hamburger_icon.addEventListener("click", changeIcon);
};

export default NavigationMenu;
```

CSS

```
.discover.show {display:block}
```

Comment: I can't see any `nav-arrow` element in your html code

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a working example of your code in a playground or jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Not sure precisely what you want to do, but generally speaking there are events that you can listen to to trigger actions such as:

```
addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {});
addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {});
addEventListener("click", (event) => {});
```